# a formal equivalent verb for 'bring (benefits) to'

Tags: word-request

In a local language there is a short phrase, used only figuratively, whose verbatim translation could be **to bring as a souvenir**. It usually appears in formal contexts where **the positive, beneficial implications** of a trend, advance, breakthrough, etc are being discussed.Simply, **to bring** is what I've found in English as a synonym for that phrase, but I'm after a more sophisticated and formal equivalent. The following context may clarify my point:

> When the mobile phone has **brought** considerable convenience,
>   people's obsession with convenience meanwhile has caused enormous
>   disturbance. That is why the use of mobile phones has been prohibited
>   in many public places.

Answer (score 2):

You might try **to grant, bequeath, or bestow.** The latter two are considerably more formal than the former, I think, although bequeath is a little antiquated.